# unknown command: crawl error

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am a newbie to python. I am running python 2.7.3 version 32 bit on 64 bit OS. (I tried 64 bit but it didn't workout).

I followed the tutorial and installed scrapy on my machine. I have created one project, demoz. But when I enter `scrapy crawl demoz` it shows an error. I came across this thing when i hit scrapy command under (C:\python27\scripts) it shows:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy
Scrapy 0.14.2 - no active project

Usage:
  scrapy <command> [options] [args]

Available commands:
  fetch         Fetch a URL using the Scrapy downloader
  runspider     Run a self-contained spider (without creating a project)
  settings      Get settings values
  shell         Interactive scraping console
  startproject  Create new project
  version       Print Scrapy version
  view          Open URL in browser, as seen by Scrapy

Use "scrapy <command> -h" to see more info about a command

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```

I guess their is something missing in installation can anybody help please .. Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? The help response for scrapy isn't going to help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 89):

You should run `scrapy crawl <your spider name>` command from being in a scrapy project folder, where `scrapy.cfg` file resides.

From the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#crawling):

> Crawling
>
> To put our spider to work, go to the project’s top level directory and run:
>
> `scrapy crawl <your spider name>`

Comment: it works fine. it is important to run crawl command in a folder contains cfg file

Answer (score 12):

You can run `scrapy crawl demoz` code from your scrapy project folder which you have created using following command

```
scrapy startproject tutorials
```

For example, if you have started scrapy project of name `tutorials`, then go to tutorials folder first and run `crawl` command from there

```
scrapy crawl demoz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already an existing project and suddenly this error "Scrapy 1.3.3 - no active project" came, in my case when I open my project, I cant see the scrapy.cfg file. What I did was, I just made some little changes on my project like removing some extra line and deployed it from github to instance and it worked!

Comment: Can you provide a `diff` of your changes, so others can see what you did? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was when i generate project
.py was out of proect then i moved into Spider folder and crawl worked.