# Scrapy does not have command 'crawl'

Tags: python, scrapy

I started to learn Scrapy but right away I get an error `Unknown command: crawl`.
I do not know why im getting this, but in py Scrapy commands I do not have that command.
Im using `python 3.6` and `pycharm` as editor.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\web skreper\venv\Scripts>scrapy crawl quotes
Scrapy 1.7.3 - no active project

Unknown command: crawl

Use "scrapy" to see available commands

(venv) C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\web skreper\venv\Scripts>scrapy
Scrapy 1.7.3 - no active project

Usage:
  scrapy <command> [options] [args]

Available commands:
  bench         Run quick benchmark test
  fetch         Fetch a URL using the Scrapy downloader
  genspider     Generate new spider using pre-defined templates
  runspider     Run a self-contained spider (without creating a project)
  settings      Get settings values
  shell         Interactive scraping console
  startproject  Create new project
  version       Print Scrapy version
  view          Open URL in browser, as seen by Scrapy
```

This is the basic code that I wrote:

```
import scrapy

class My_Scraper(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'quotes'

    #url sajtova koje scrapujem
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.nekretnine.rs/'
        ]

    def parse(self, response):

        title = response.css('title').extract()

        yield {'title text': title}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unknown command: crawl error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123104/unknown-command-crawl-error)

Comment: You should run scrapy crawl spider_name command being in a scrapy project folder, where the scrapy.cfg file resides.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123104/unknown-command-crawl-error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be inside the project folder within the Scrapy folder.

You are currently trying to run the command from C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\web skreper\venv\Scripts

but it should be something like C:\Users\Pc\PycharmProjects\web skreper\venv\Scripts\Scrapy\My_Scraper

Answer (score 8):

You must get out from the script folder and move to the project directory where `scrapy.cfg` file placed.

Run the scrapy crawl from there it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post but I would also like to contribute an additional instance that may result in the missing of crawl command

if you accidentally delete the cfg file, crawl command will disappear too.